# Sum of independent RVs a.s. constant implies each RV to be a.s. constant.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X, Y$ be two independent random variables and $X+Y \equiv c \in \mathbb{R}$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

Show that $X,Y$ are almost surely constant.

This question [has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244168/sum-of-independent-random-variables-being-a-s-constant-implies-that-each-of-the), however, I got a hint for an alternative approach:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X = Y) &= \left( \mathbb{P}^{X} \otimes\mathbb{P}^{Y}\right) \left(\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x=y\} \right)\\
&= \int \int \mathbb{1}_{\{(x,y) | x=y\}} d\mathbb{P}^{X} d\mathbb{P}^{Y} \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\{y\}} d\mathbb{P}^{X} \mathbb{P}^{Y}(y)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}(X = y) d\mathbb{P}^{Y}(y).\\
\end{align*}$$

Why is it sufficient to look at the event of the two being equal? As far as I understand, $X, Y$ could have different values. Shouldn't we rather be looking at something like $\mathbb{P}(X = c - Y)$ to begin with?

Comment: $X=Y$ is for $X-Y=0$.  Indeed you want $X=c-Y$ in this case instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you really want to look at $X=c-Y$.
Then
$$
1=\mathbb{P}(X=c-Y)=\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}(X=c-y)\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}^Y(y)\leq\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(X=c-y)
$$
so $X$ is constant $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

Comment: The conclusion $$\mathbb{P}(X=a) = 1 \text{ for one } a \in \mathbb{R}$$ is not right, because $$1 = \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(X=c-y) \nRightarrow \mathbb{P}(X=c-y) =1.$$ Take $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^+} 1-\frac{1}{x} = 1 \text{, while } 1-\frac{1}{x} < 1 \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+.$$

Comment: $X=c-y$, $X=c-y'$ are disjoint events.  So you cannot have any $y$ such that $0<\mathbb{P}(X=c-y)<1$ without contradicting either $\sup_y\mathbb{P}(X=c-y)=1$ or $\mathbb{P}$ a probability measure.

Comment: How to prove $\{X = a\} \cap \{X = b\} = \emptyset$ for $a \neq b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Suppose you can find $\omega\in\{X=a\}\cap\{X=b\}$.  What is $X(\omega)$?

Comment: $X(\omega) = \{a,b\}$, which cannot be since $X$ is a random variable.

Comment: Erm.. I suppose you can say that.  The usual argument: Since $\omega\in\{X=a\}$, $X(\omega)=a$, and we also have $X(\omega)=b$ by the same reason, so $a=b$ contradiction.

Comment: To finish the proof, we have:
$$
sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}(X=x) = 1 \\
\Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon >0 \ \exists \ a_{\varepsilon} : 1-\varepsilon < P(X=a_{\varepsilon}).
$$
Suppose
$$
0 <\mathbb{P}(X = a) = p < 1 \text{ for one } a \in \mathbb{R}, \\ \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\{X = a\}^c) = 1 - p.
$$
Suppose $a \neq a_\varepsilon$:
$$
\cap_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\{X = x\}=\emptyset \text{, thus} 
\{X = a_\varepsilon\} \subset \{X = a\}^c.\\
\Rightarrow  \mathbb{P}(X = a_\varepsilon) \leq 1-p, \text{ contradction for } \varepsilon < p,\\
\Rightarrow a_\varepsilon = a.
$$

Comment: But then we also have
$$
\forall \varepsilon >0  : 1-\varepsilon < p\text{, contradction since } p < 1.
$$